# Tail recursion (@tailrec) recursive function vs non-recursive function scala stack overflow error?

Tags: scala, recursion, stack-overflow, tail-recursion, akka-stream

My use-case is more complicated but basically below is the simplified example of what I am trying to achieve (my original code is for akka-stream):

```
offset := 0

//pump data
def pump(): Unit = {
    elem := poller.getNumberFromOffset(offset)

    elem match {
        case null => doSomething()
        case Completed => doSomethingElse()
        case _ => 
            offset += 1
            //check if the element is matched with a pre-supplied selector/filter function
            if(filterFunc(elem)) {
                doSomething2()
            } else {
                //if the element doesn't match; increase offset and try again; can sleep for a while here               
                pump()
            }
    }
}
```

The problem is that pump() function might result in stack-overflow (because pump function is called over-and-over again for a specific condition).

I can write the function into a non-recursive version like the following:

```
offset := 0

//pump data
def pump(): Unit = {
    elem := poller.getNumberFromOffset(offset)
    while(elem != null && elem != Completed && !filterFunc(elem)) {
        offset += 1
        elem = poller.getNumberFromOffset(offset)
    }       

    elem match {
        case null => doSomething()
        case Completed => doSomethingElse()
        case _ =>           
            offset += 1
            doSomething2()
    }
}
```

However my use-case is much more complicated; so I would really like to use the recursion function if it's possible instead of converting the existing code to while/for loop.

My question is "should I do so" and is there any difference if I just simply put @tailrec annotation on the first example so that scala complier will treat pump as tail-recursion function (@tailrec def pump(): Unit = {}). In my case, the pump() function should be called separatedly / after fixed interval; so stack-frame is really not necessary here.

Thanks.

Comment: "is there any difference if I just simply put `@tailrec` annotation on the first example" – No. The `@tailrec` annotation makes no difference. Tail-recursive methods are always optimized. (More precisely: methods that satisfy [the conditions laid out in the spec](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#function-applications).) The only thing the `@tailrec` annotation does is generate a compiler error if the method is not tail-recursive. [It does *not* change whether or not the method gets optimized.](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/tailrec.html)

Comment: I challenge your pattern matching on `null`. Instead, I would wrap your possible `null` value in [Option#apply](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.Option$@apply[A](x:A):Option[A]). Example: `Option[String] { null }` === `None`

Answer (score 1):

If you put `@tailrec` and the compiler lets you run it, this implies your piece of code is eligible for tail recursion optimization. Internally scala compiler will convert the tail recursive code to a loop. I dont think a tail recursive function will cause a stackoverflow error.So your pump() function wont cause stackoverflow if it satisfies `@tailrec`.